# How to make my Garage Band '11 ringtone louder?

Tags: itunes, iphone, garageband

I created a ringtone using **Garage Band '11** and my bass directly inputted to my MAC. I was able to create the ringtone I wanted, and selected the 30 second loop, however the volume is really low. I've tried bumping up the volume on both the track and the monitor locations but still way lower than, say a purchased ringtone.

Anyone know of a place I may be overlooking?

**UPDATE:**

I adjusted the settings in preferences under Audio/MIDI[image: Audio/Midi settings window]

And I also unchecked `Export Projects at Full Loudness` just to see if there was any difference in the output. But it sounded identical to the previous export:
[image: Advanced Settings]

Comment: Is the input from your bass routed through the usual input channels? Did you check the volume settings in Preferences for the corresponding channel?

Comment: My guess is the export to iTunes has a volume normalization step. Have you played with limiters or compression to remove the peaks (and make the rest louder) or otherwise [run the master track](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yeI7Ip39kIE) through [the compressor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_range_compression#Marketing) to make the sound denser?

Comment: Thanks patrix. I adjusted the settings in Preferences but I don't hear a difference yet.

Comment: Thanks bmike, I found the `Compressor` settings in the `Master Track`. And it helped a bit. I also found the `Visual EQ` to be quite effective. The `Visual EQ` settings are in the same area, so your comment lead me to the answer I was looking for!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that works for me. Thanks to **bmike** for pointing me in the right direction. What I used was the `Visual EQ` to bump up the `Output level` of my master track. The `Visual EQ` is found under `Master Effects` of the `Master Track` window:

[image: Visual EQ is found under Master Effects]

I adjusted to taste and **boom!** I've got a much better volume level for my ringtone.

[image: Visual EQ window]